# Duplicate HTTP Request in java web application using tomcat behind apache & proxy - Ajax/Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, apache, tomcat

### Environment

We have a java based web application running in a corporate environment with users behind a proxy. The web application has tomcat on the same server with apache web server sitting in the front. Please also note we have restricted access to the overall environment so the solutions were implemented on guess work. We can access application server however.

### Background

We have a web page in the application that allows user to upload files, the file gets processed and a log file is created. The files takes some time to process, sometimes as high as 10-20 minutes. The log file created has the timestamp appended to its name. This timestamp for log file is generated every time the web page loads. The log file name is also shown in the text box field on the web page with its current value (e.g. log_2017-02-19 01.18.24.html). So it's always visible to users.

### Initial Problem

The initial problem we had was that duplicate requests were getting generated and as a result the same file submitted by user was getting processed multiple times. Users confirmed they were not submitting the same request multiple times.

### Solutions Implemented

- We first implemented an ajax/javascript based solution to remove postback/page-refresh upon submitting files. We also used javascript to hide submit button as soon as the file was submitted to ensure the users do not resubmit the request by mistake. The ajax/js solution used POST method and reloaded the page after an interval of 29 seconds upon receiving a response from server.
- Reviewing the application http logs we saw that the created log files were having exact same timestamp value for the duplicate requests. We then thought it was the proxy that was sending the duplicate request, without users knowing, assuming that the upstream server timed out. We kept the ajax based solution in place but now introduced a tomcat filter to intercept the post request. We look for the incoming log file name request parameter and blocked it in case if a duplicate was found. This prevented the duplicates generated by the proxy.

### Current Problem

Now we are having the same duplicate file processing problem but this time the log files generated do not have the exact same timestamp. Below is a scenario.

- At 11:08:14: User loads the web page to upload file. Potential log file name shown is log_2017-03-29 11.08.14
- At 11:08:28: User submits file for processing and the log file log_2017-03-29 11.08.14.html gets created.
- At 11:08:57: Page reloads 29 seconds later after user submits file (as per Ajax/js based solution)
- At 11:11:56: Duplicate request gets generated somehow and the log file log_2017-03-29 11.08.57.html gets created.
- At 11:12:25: the Page then reloads in 29 using javascript.

Users have confirmed again they are not submitting the duplicate request. Has this behavior observed by anyone in a web application? Could it be ajax or javascript getting triggered on its own even after the page reloads? Or perhaps the onclick handler of the submit button gets automatically fired up ?

Thoughts please?

Comment: facing the same issue .... were you able to find the root cause and solution to this ?